# Lost RDP session on gcp VM(windows server 2016) afer changing firewall settings

Tags: remote-desktop, google-compute-engine, windows-firewall, google-cloud-storage

I lost my RDP session after setting up some firewall settings on my GCP windows VM and now that is unreachable via IP or RDP or URL. I tried pinging that IP but request timed out.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Have you tried to connect to your VM via [Windows SAC](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-windows#connecting_to_the_windows_sac) and [disable your firewall rule](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/disable-netfirewallrule?view=windowsserver2019-ps)?

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza Thank you for your help brother. You saved me. I was working to find the solution for last 2 days. Your answer gave me a proper direction and I found this article which resolved my problem.

https://blog.doit-intl.com/restoring-windows-server-access-via-the-google-cloud-serial-consol-5023837c8cda

Comment: Nice to hear that. Please upvote/accept my answer if it was helpful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was discussed at the comments section, **to solve this issue** you should connect to your VM instance via serial console and then remove the firewall rule. More details you can find at the documentation [Windows SAC](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-windows#connecting_to_the_windows_sac).

As it was mentioned by *@Jamil Aslam*, [this article](https://blog.doit-intl.com/restoring-windows-server-access-via-the-google-cloud-serial-consol-5023837c8cda) shows an example of such action.